# Docusign webservice using vb.net - anchor tags Custom

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

Here is the problem I am having.

I have a document that I am creating using the DocuSign webservice.

I can create normal fields/tabs on it ie SignHere / SignDate / Initial fields.

However when i wan to use a custom field it just doesn't work. The code runs and the document is sent but all that is in the place of the EXPECTED custom field is just a bisc text box. It's like it's just ignoring the custom field settings.

I have attached the document i am using for reference and my code is below.

Everything works but the parts where the 2 customer fields should be I think is the issue.

```
Dim DocuSignSoap As New ServiceReference2.DSAPIServiceSoapClient
Dim DocuSignRecipient(0) As ServiceReference2.Recipient
Dim DocuSignRecipientType As ServiceReference2.RecipientTypeCode
Dim DocuSignTabType As ServiceReference2.TabTypeCode
Dim DocuSignCustomTabType As ServiceReference2.CustomTabType
Dim DocuSignEnvelope As New ServiceReference2.Envelope
Dim DocuSignDocument(0) As ServiceReference2.Document
Dim DocuSignTab(7) As ServiceReference2.Tab
Dim DocuSignEnvelopeStatus As ServiceReference2.EnvelopeStatus
Dim DocusignSig1 As New ServiceReference2.AnchorTab
Dim DocusignSig2 As New ServiceReference2.AnchorTab
Dim DocusignDateLOA As New ServiceReference2.AnchorTab
Dim DocusignDDDate As New ServiceReference2.AnchorTab
Dim DocusignFreq1 As New ServiceReference2.AnchorTab
Dim DocusignFreq2 As New ServiceReference2.AnchorTab
Dim DocusignFreq3 As New ServiceReference2.AnchorTab
Dim DocusignFreq4 As New ServiceReference2.AnchorTab
Dim strAuth As String
Dim strDocID As String

strDocID = Format(Now, "ddMMyyyyhhmmss")

Dim Mystream As New FileStream("c:\dantestdocusign.pdf", FileMode.Open)
Dim filesize As Long = Mystream.Length
Dim buffer(filesize) As Byte

Mystream.Read(buffer, 0, filesize)
Mystream.Close()

'Create Recipent
DocuSignRecipient(0) = New ServiceReference2.Recipient
DocuSignRecipient(0).Email = "daniel.rodgers@idebtplan.co.uk"
DocuSignRecipient(0).UserName = "Daniel Rodgers"
DocuSignRecipient(0).SignerName = "Daniel Rodgers"
DocuSignRecipient(0).Type = DocuSignRecipientType.Signer
DocuSignRecipient(0).ID = "1"
DocuSignRecipient(0).RoutingOrder = 1

'Create the envelope content
DocuSignEnvelope.Subject = "Your iDebtPlan Pack"
DocuSignEnvelope.EmailBlurb = "Email content"
DocuSignEnvelope.Recipients = DocuSignRecipient
DocuSignEnvelope.AccountId = "2f447fb0-243a-4a3f-acb5-adefbef43492"

'Create the document
DocuSignDocument(0) = New ServiceReference2.Document
DocuSignDocument(0).ID = strDocID
DocuSignDocument(0).Name = "DAN TESTING DOC"
DocuSignDocument(0).PDFBytes = buffer

' Attach the document(s)
DocuSignEnvelope.Documents = DocuSignDocument

' Create a new signature tab 1
DocuSignTab(0) = New ServiceReference2.Tab
DocuSignTab(0).DocumentID = DocuSignDocument(0).ID
DocuSignTab(0).RecipientID = "1"
DocuSignTab(0).Type = DocuSignTabType.SignHere
DocusignSig1.AnchorTabString = "\s1\"
DocuSignTab(0).AnchorTabItem = DocusignSig1
DocuSignTab(0).TabLabel = "Sig1"

' Create a new signature tab 2
DocuSignTab(1) = New ServiceReference2.Tab
DocuSignTab(1).DocumentID = DocuSignDocument(0).ID
DocuSignTab(1).RecipientID = "1"
DocuSignTab(1).Type = DocuSignTabType.SignHere
DocusignSig2.AnchorTabString = "\s2\"
DocuSignTab(1).AnchorTabItem = DocusignSig2
DocuSignTab(1).TabLabel = "Sig2"

' Create a DateLOA
DocuSignTab(2) = New ServiceReference2.Tab
DocuSignTab(2).DocumentID = DocuSignDocument(0).ID
DocuSignTab(2).RecipientID = "1"
DocuSignTab(2).Type = DocuSignTabType.DateSigned
DocusignDateLOA.AnchorTabString = "\loadate\"
DocuSignTab(2).AnchorTabItem = DocusignDateLOA
DocuSignTab(2).TabLabel = "DateLOA"

'CUSTOM FIELD 1
' Create a DD Date
DocuSignTab(3) = New ServiceReference2.Tab
DocuSignTab(3).DocumentID = DocuSignDocument(0).ID
DocuSignTab(3).RecipientID = "1"
DocuSignTab(3).Type = 11
DocuSignTab(3).CustomTabType = 4 'date
DocuSignTab(3).CustomTabWidth = 100
DocuSignTab(3).CustomTabDisableAutoSize = True
DocuSignTab(3).CustomTabRequired = True
DocuSignTab(3).CustomTabValidationPattern ="(^(?:(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/0?2|(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[469]|11)|(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))/\d{4}$)"
DocuSignTab(3).MaxLength = 10
DocuSignTab(3).CustomTabValidationMessage = "Your First Payment Date
Must be format dd/mm/yyyy (example: 01/03/2012), and a valid UK Date"
DocusignDDDate.AnchorTabString = "\dddate\"
DocuSignTab(3).AnchorTabItem = DocusignDDDate
DocuSignTab(3).TabLabel = "DDDate"

'CUSTOM FIELD 2
''Create Frequency Radio Buttons
DocuSignTab(4) = New ServiceReference2.Tab
DocuSignTab(4).DocumentID = DocuSignDocument(0).ID
DocuSignTab(4).RecipientID = "1"
DocuSignTab(4).Type = 11
DocuSignTab(4).CustomTabType = 2 'radio
DocuSignTab(4).CustomTabRequired = True
DocuSignTab(4).CustomTabWidth = 100
DocuSignTab(4).CustomTabDisableAutoSize = True
DocuSignTab(4).CustomTabRadioGroupName = "Frequency"
DocuSignTab(4).TabLabel = "Frequency"
DocuSignTab(4).Value = ""
DocusignFreq1.AnchorTabString = "\ow\"
DocuSignTab(4).AnchorTabItem = DocusignFreq1
DocuSignEnvelope.Tabs = DocuSignTab

strAuth = "<DocuSignCredentials<Usernameinfo@idebtplan.co.uk<mailto:info@idebtplan.co.uk</Username<Passwordjemima79</Password<IntegratorKeyIDEB-8ce296aa-0dff-4347-8ece-b62836a6a94e</IntegratorKey</DocuSignCredentials"


Dim x As New OperationContextScope(DocuSignSoap.InnerChannel)
Dim httpRequest As New System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty
httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", strAuth)
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties(httpRequest.Name) = httpRequest

' Create the envelope on the account -- it will be a draft
DocuSignEnvelopeStatus = DocuSignSoap.CreateAndSendEnvelope(DocuSignEnvelope)
buffer = Nothing
Mystream = Nothing
httpRequest = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Try adding your custom fields without the use of anchor tabs (i.e. use absolute positioning)
2. Compare how you are configuring your custom fields with the sample code from the [SOAP SDK up on GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK).
3. Create the envelope using the newer REST API from DocuSign.